# How do you detect and identify Javascript/jQuery conflicts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, detection, conflict

I am working with multiple jQuery plugins and while the configuration scripts are tried and tested in separate implementations, the combination of the plugins is causing their behaviors to either not function as intended or not function at all.

Is there a proper method or means to detecting if there are conflicts in Javascript, and specifically identifying what the conflicts are, in order to resolve them?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The developer console is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You need Firebug (Mozilla) or Web Inspector (Webkit)

Comment: In the interest of constructive input, please elaborate or refrain from responding.

Comment: Why do you need me to tell you something Google is much better at? I've taken you to the water, you only have to drink.

Comment: This isn't drinking water, it's debugging code through a fairly complex tool. I've been wrangling with Firebug in the console for hours to no avail - it does not detect any conflicts, yet I know they are there because when the script I'm using (jQuery Tools) is removed it fixes the issue - the issue being that the script conflicts with Firebug somehow and crashes Firefox. I'm trying to solicit exact steps or methods for pinpointing the conflict.

Comment: Did you disable Firebug and see if it works in Firefox? That would narrow it down some.

Comment: @nikeaa Thanks, tried that and it appears to be the issue. Looks like jQuery Tools is conflicting with Firebug. Still looking into how, and how it can be resolved.

Comment: You could try getting a non-minified version of jQuery Tools and commenting it out, one piece at a time, until the conflict goes away. At least that would tell you where in jQuery Tools the conflict is.